# background images don't show/are stretched on iPad or iPhone

Tags: html, css, iphone, ipad, background-image

I have a [website](http://calebbertrand.github.io) on github pages, which works perfectly on any desktop browser. However, two of my background images will not show up on mobile devices (I've only tested iPad and iPhone, it could just be IOS). I have tried adding media queries to make sure the `background-attachment` property is set to `scroll` on handheld devices (I had read this was sometimes the problem). I also have media queries that ensure the images are not too large to load. Here is my html:

```
<div id="image-1" class="background-image"></div>
<div id="image-2" class="background-image"></div>
```

Here's the css:

```
#image-1 {
  background-image: url('imgs/coding.jpg');
}
#image-2 {
  background-image: url("imgs/game.JPG");
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
    /* For mobile phones: */
    #image-1 {
      background-image: url("imgs/coding-large.jpg");
    }
    #image-2 {
      background-image: url("imgs/game-large.jpg");
    }
}
@media not handheld {
    .background-image {
      background-attachment: fixed;
    }
}
.background-image {
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-size: 100% 100vh;
  height: 85vh;
}
```

If I change 100vh to 100%, then the images load, but they are terribly stretched vertically. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either:

- use a fixed position, with a background position `center center`: see "[CSS background-size: cover replacement for Mobile Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21456799/6309)".
  [This page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42640345/background-images-dont-show-are-stretched-on-ipad-or-iphone/42640531#42640531) refers to a `background-attachment: fixed;` as well, while remining use that viewport values (such as `vh` and `vw`) are technically supported on iOS 7 but simply do not work, hence the [`rodneyrehm/viewport-units-buggyfill`](https://github.com/rodneyrehm/viewport-units-buggyfill) project.
- or (less elegant), use fixed size for media with a given size: see "[Background image not displayed properly on iPad and iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23015545/6309)"

Answer (score 2):

Seems iPhones disregard `@media` rules for `handheld` devices (See here [Do iPhone / Android browsers support CSS @media handheld?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893342/do-iphone-android-browsers-support-css-media-handheld)
). And giving `background-size` property of `100% 100%` will make the image stretched if the image is not square.

So you can use `max-width` media query to detect mobile devices and set `background-attachment` as `scroll`. And either use `background-size: cover` or background-size: `100% auto`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have competing heights with your background-size attribute and your background height attribute. Check out [CSS-Trick's post on background-sizes for a better implementation](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-size/). Since it looks like you want to cover the width of the page with the images, go with `background-size:cover` instead. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
/* Image is centered vertically and horizontally at all times */
background-position: center center;

/* Image doesn't repeat */
background-repeat: no-repeat;

/* Makes the image fixed in the viewport so that it doesn't move when
the content height is greater than the image height */
background-attachment: fixed;

/* This is what makes the background image rescale based on its     container's size */
background-size: cover;
```